# How I can set-up MySQL on Lubuntu for education purpose?

Tags: lubuntu, mysql

I have Lubuntu 12.10 x86 on my notebook with all updates. I downloaded and install MySQL Community Server and MySQL Workbench. I learning Java and our next lesson will be about MySQL. I need to prepare - create test database. If I understand - I need use terminal for creating database? I tried `mysql -u root -p` and after entering password I get: `ERROR 2002 (HYOOO) Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. And I don't have this directory: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.

I read some pages about this problem and it is not still repaired.

Comment: If you use **mysql -u root -p** insted of **mysqladmin** the problem persists?

Comment: Oh, I was wrong - I got 2002 error when `mysql -u root -p`. When `mysqladmin -u root -p` I got long list with "Administration program for the mysqld daemon".

Comment: Is the MySQL server running? Make sure it is running by using the command `sudo service mysql start` Did you download/install the program from MySQL's website, or use the packages from Ubuntu, either through Software Center or apt-get?

Comment: please do a `ps -ef | grep mysql` on command line. If it returns no process mysql is NOT running (or not installed). If so see user1262738's answer .

Comment: `sudo service mysql start` - `mysql: unrecognized service`

Comment: `ps -ef | grep mysql` - `vitaly    2304  2253  0 18:28 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get mysql server status by entering `sudo service mysqld status`

If it is not running start it by entering `sudo service mysqld start`

If you get `service not recognised` message, install mysql server by entering:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

This will install mysql, then start it by entering `sudo service mysqld start`

Comment: Yes, `not recognized`, but why, if I installed MySQL Community Server from official site? And is not bad that installed Community Server version 6 but `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` has version 5.5? Now I installing this.

Comment: Installed mysql-server. I tried `CREATE DATABASE database1` and after this I have `->` symbol and nothing happen.

Comment: Oh, I was needed ";" and the end of `CREATE DATABASE database1`.

Comment: I connected Workbench to my created database, and I prepared for course. Only question that I have - why I was needed make `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` if I had installed MySQL Community Edition?

Comment: when you install community edition you have to start the daemon, ubuntu packages are ready to use in services, it is always a better way to install from apt repository because configuration files for that specific distro are ready to use..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the newest community server from dev.mysql.com I like to advice you to not download the .deb-package but the Generic Linux tarball for your architecture (32/64 bit) and install it as detailed in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-installation.html. Prior to this remove any existing parts of the old server.

During the installation procedure as described create a /etc/my.cnf before you first start the server. The template my-medium.cnf from the support-files directory is always a good starting point.